# JQM 1.4.5 and splitview Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on pagecontainer prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'change'

Tags: jquery-mobile, splitview

Jquery.mobile.splitview  for jquery.mobile-1.4.5 error

```
"cannot call methods on pagecontainer prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'change'"
```

It cause by upgrade JQM 1.2.1 to JQM 1.4.5 with no jquery.mobile.splitview upgrade.

Question: Is there any jquery.mobile.splitview for JQM 1.4.5

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on pagecontainer prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'change'
    at Function.error (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:254:9)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.self-31d65ee183ce6d4c0e27b21fad8429156ee18d418063e7f9caf860b612092cc8.js?body=1:928:15)
    at Function.each (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:371:19)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:138:17)
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.(anonymous function) [as pagecontainer] (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.self-31d65ee183ce6d4c0e27b21fad8429156ee18d418063e7f9caf860b612092cc8.js?body=1:920:9)
    at Object.$.mobile.changePage (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.self-31d65ee183ce6d4c0e27b21fad8429156ee18d418063e7f9caf860b612092cc8.js?body=1:5845:26)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.mobile.splitview.self-e15baccb65d7aa3afefe9b440484be73123530a8d491f74c462e7f9b27757ac8.js?body=1:34:20
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.turbolinks.self-176b9819f30444d441e820bbccd3264fe57753aeafd54dec732b0dbc77129a2a.js?body=1:30:16)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:5227:27)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:4879:28)
jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:254 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on pagecontainer prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'change'
    at Function.error (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:254:9)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.self-31d65ee183ce6d4c0e27b21fad8429156ee18d418063e7f9caf860b612092cc8.js?body=1:928:15)
    at Function.each (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:371:19)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:138:17)
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.(anonymous function) [as pagecontainer] (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.self-31d65ee183ce6d4c0e27b21fad8429156ee18d418063e7f9caf860b612092cc8.js?body=1:920:9)
    at Object.$.mobile.changePage (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.self-31d65ee183ce6d4c0e27b21fad8429156ee18d418063e7f9caf860b612092cc8.js?body=1:5845:26)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.mobile.splitview.self-e15baccb65d7aa3afefe9b440484be73123530a8d491f74c462e7f9b27757ac8.js?body=1:34:20
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.turbolinks.self-176b9819f30444d441e820bbccd3264fe57753aeafd54dec732b0dbc77129a2a.js?body=1:30:16)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:5227:27)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:4879:28)
```

But after I changed order of //= require to load jquery.mobile-1.4.5 before jquery.mobile.splitview the error disappeared.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
// require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.mobile-1.4.5
//= require jquery.mobile.splitview
//= require jquery.mobile.datebox
//= require iscroll-wrapper
//= require iscroll
//= require turbolinks
//= require ckeditor/init
// require rails-ujs
```

New issue: The screen not split as supposed to be [here](http://asyraf9.github.io/jquerymobile-splitview/#source) but shown [image: no-split]

After read others questions, I suspected the function $.mobile.changePage in [jquery.mobile.splitview.js](https://github.com/asyraf9/jquerymobile-splitview/blob/master/src/jquery.mobile.splitview.js) was deprecated in JQM-1.4.5

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: When I replaced JQM 1.2.1 with JQM 1.4.5 in my app that use jquery.mobile.splitview (for 1.2.1) I debug and found error from old jquery.mobile.splitview.js

Comment: Are you running any script on load?

Comment: oh, I tried changed order of require then no error now but another issue came up it's screen not split anymore. I will edit my question to include new issue.